# Open-circuit Output Voltage of Bipolar Output Stage

Tags: transistors

In TI's doc [Designing With Logic](http://www.ti.com.cn/cn/lit/an/sdya009c/sdya009c.pdf), p. 16, it shows a method to calculate the internal resistance (\$R_{o}\$): using the open-circuit output voltage (\$V_{o}\$) and short-circuit current (\$I_{os}\$).

$$
R_{o} = \frac{V_{o}}{I_{os}}
$$

[image]

I can understand the method to get \$R_{o}\$, but i can't understand how get the 'open-circuit output voltage', if it's output floating, ideally there will no current flow in Q1 and Q2, where the voltage come from?

Comment: Perhaps the C_load (CL) is what contains voltage, and is assumed charged at the point of the open circuit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice how at \$Io \gtrapprox 0\$, Vo drops sharply from Vcc down to 3.5V. This is the output voltage with *just enough load* to bias Q1+Q2 so \$ V_o = V_{cc} - R_1 \cdot I(R_1) - V_{be}(Q_1) - V_{be}(Q_2)\$ with \$I(R_1) = I_b(Q_1) \approx 0\$. That's a bit less than 5v - 0.7v - 0.7v = 3.6v.

Comment: Yes, so it can't be 'open circuit' entirely, from the graph at right, Ios is not start from zero.

Comment: @diverger: the axis should be labeled 'Io', which does equal 0 with a disconnected output.  'Ios' is the value where the plot crosses 0V ("Io, short circuit"). The plot is missing the leftmost bit at Vo=Vcc, Io=0; the author must have left it out because it's not relevant to the dV/dI=Ro linearization.

Comment: You mean the the point (Io = 0, Vo = Vcc) does exist? If the Io = 0, the output will float entirely, where the Vo come from?

Comment: Vo will come from the transistor that drives the base of Q1. Think of the diode curve: with zero load, the B-E junctions of Q1, Q2 are at 0v, but any significant current will increase Vbe and Vo will drop, which is what you see at the left of the plot.